# S3 Slow Down exception for Spark program

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have simple spark program running in EMR cluster trying to convert 60 GB of CSV file into parquet. When i submit the job i get below exception.

```
391, ip-172-31-36-116.us-west-2.compute.internal, executor 96): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:196)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Slow Down (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: 503 Slow Down; Request ID: D13A3F4D7DD970FA; S3 Extended Request ID: gj3cPalkkOwtaf9XN/P+sb3jX0CNHu/QF9WTabkgP2ISuXcXdbvYO1Irg0O54OCvKlLz8WoR8E4=), S3 Extended Request ID: gj3cPalkkOwtaf9XN/P+sb3jX0CNHu/QF9WTabkgP2ISuXcXdbvYO1Irg0O54OCvKlLz8WoR8E4=
at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1639)
```

Answer (score 5):

`503 Slow Down` is a generic response from AWS services when you're doing too many requests per second.

Possible solutions:

1. Copy your file to HDFS first.
2. Do you have one 60 Gb file or a lot of files that sums up to 60 Gb? If you have a lot of small files, try to combine them first.
3. Try to decrease the number of partitions in your Parquet output, if you can. 
   `df.repartition(100)`
4. Try using less Spark workers.
   `val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").master("local[1]").getOrCreate()`

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that things failed; the Apache s3a client backs off when it sees a problem like this: your work is done, just more slowly.

All of Sergey's advice is good. I'd start by coalescing small files and reducing workers: a smaller cluster can deliver more performance, *and save money*.

One more: if you are using SSE-KMS to encrypt the data, accessing that key can trigger throttle events too; throttling shared across all applications trying to use the KMS store.

Comment: thanks for your response. yes am using KMS for encryption. but it is KMS/s3.  AS a workaround i have written the data to hdfs and then tried to do s3-dist-cp  still the same error during s3-dist-cp

Comment: second thing is as am using EMR cluster i think t is not using apache s3a filesystem. it should be using EMRFS library.